# I can't make a modal for my site

Tags: php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've been trying to make a Modal appear for a few weeks now but it does not work sadly. I've tried bootstrap, which was the simplest way I could find out there using a Quick Google search but bootstrap modals affect my css classes and how my entire webpage is already styled.

I'll just paste my entire index code here for reference. It'll be nice if someone here can help me with my issue.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>

            <!--Chat name -->
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["steamname"])){

$user = $_SESSION["steamname"];

}

else {
    $user = "";
}
?>

    <title>CSGORised - Coinflip</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
 family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Chat.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" 
rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="ChatPoster.php"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-
awesome.min.css">
    <script src="GetMessages.php"></script>
    <script src="openid/openid.php"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" 
rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="createGame.js"></script>


</head>


<body>


<div id="displaybar">
</div>




    <style>

    .session-steam-id {
    position: fixed;
    top: 158px;
    left: 87px;
    width: 165px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color: #b107b7;
    text-decoration: none
    }



     .steam-pic {
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: fixed;
     top: 150px;
     left: 28px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     align-content: center;
    }

    </style>


    <div id="rectangle"></div>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION["steamname"]))
        //If steamname not equals 0
            {   

                     echo '<a class="button-logout" 
href="steamauth/logout.php">Log Out</a>';

                }
            else
                {
                    echo '<a class="button-login" 
href="steamauth/login_steam.php">Log In</a>';

                }
        ?>

    </div>
    <?php
    $steamphoto = $_SESSION["profileimg"];
    ?>


    <div id="top6"></div>
    <div id="top1"></div>
    <div id="toolbar2">
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["steamname"]))
        //If steamname not equals 0
            {   
                echo "<img class=\"steam-pic\" src='$steamphoto'>";
                echo "<div class=\"session-steam-id\">$user</div>"; 
            }
            else {
                '';
            } ?>



    </div>


    <h1>CSGORised</h1>


                <!--The side buttons-->

    <div>   

    <a class="button-support" href="etc/support.php">Support</a>
    <a class="button-FAQ" href="etc/FAQ.php">FAQ</a>
    <a class="button-Provably-fair" href="etc/provablyfair.php">Provably 
Fair</a>
    <a class="button-about-us" href="etc/aboutus.php">About us</a>
    <a class="button-terms-and-co" href="etc/tandc.php">Terms and 
Conditions</a>
    <a class="button-entertainment" 
href="etc/entertainment.php">Entertainment</a>


    </div>

            <!--End of the side buttons-->

    <div style="text-align: center"><a 
href="https://youtube.com/garlicyvideos"target="_blank"><img class="img-
youtube" src=https://developers.google.com/youtube/images/YouTube-icon-
full_color.png alt="Garlicvideos's Youtube" height="42" breadth="42"/></a>
</div>

    <div style="text-align: center"><a 
href="https://www.instagram.com/csgorised"target="_blank"><img class="img-
instagram" 
src=http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c521.png 
alt="Our Official Instagram!" height="42" breadth="42"/></a></div>

    <div class='chatContainer' style="position: fixed;">
        <div class='chatMessages'></div>
        <div class='chatbottom'>
            <form action='#' onSubmit='return false;' id='chatForm'>
                <input type='hidden' id='name' value='<?php echo $user ?>' 
/>
                <input type='text' name='text' id='text' value='' 
placeholder='Say something
                ' />
                <input type='submit' name='<i>submit</i>' value='Say' />
                </form>

    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no modal in your code!?

Comment: @Jeff Yeah I removed it due to it not working. I tried what this site told me https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp